# Intercepting Alamofire responses

Tags: ios, alamofire

I need to be able to intercept all the requests' responses in order to override the default implementation of `case .failure(let error)` as in the closure below:

```
apiClient.request("some url", method: .post, parameters: ..., encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: sessionHeaders).validate(statusCode: 200...200).responseObject(queue: DispatchQueue.global(), completionHandler: { [weak self] (response:  DataResponse<ResponseObject<ObjectX>>) in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            switch response.result{
            case .success(_):

            case .failure(let error):
                // Handle error
            }
        }
```

so instead of doing the same implementation for each response, I need to be able to that in one place. 
I found in the doc something called `RequestAdapter` however, this works only for the requests before being fired.

Comment: Maybe try `URLProtocol`?

Comment: @Brandon is that has a thing to do with Alamofire? or it's just a separate thing?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in the common error handler? If you make your requests generically, then all requests can share the same error handling logic.

Comment: @Brandon I am trying to determine if a status code (401) occurred to take the appropriate action, what do you mean with "make your requests generically"? can you plz clarify more.

Comment: Use generics so all of your requests use the same Alamofire invocation. Then you can have a single response handler. Or, if you need to retry requests on a 401 response, you can use Alamofire's `RequestRetrier`.